# Angular CDK Overlay Animation on overlay works only on first time

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-overlay

I'm trying to implement a generic auto completion.

My code is structured in following way

1. `dsAutocomplete` directive is top level directive
2. `dsAutocompleteInputTrigger` is directive attached to `<input>` element
3. `dsAutoCompleteOrigin` is attached to element on whose drop down need to be anchored
4. `*dsAutocompletePanel` is a structural directive to define what is dropdown

Flow of actions is

For opening
`dsAutocompleteInputTrigger.focus` -> `dsAutocomplete.openPanel` -> `overlayRef.attach(TemplatePortal(dsAutocompletePanel))` as FlexibleConnected to `dsAutoCompleteOrigin`

For closing
`dsAutocompleteInputTrigger.focusout` -> `dsAutocomplete.closePanel` -> `overlayRef.detach()`

when I add an animation directive any where in AutoComplete Panel it only works first time

The code is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-smmzcq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

#### Environment

- Angular:13.2
- CDK/Material:13.2
- Browser(s):Firefox , Chrome
- Operating System:Windows 11

Upsteam issue https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As upstream issue https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24749 is fixed
Animations work as expected